# User login authentication does not work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to log a user into my rails site via the login page. My user enters in their email and password in order to log in, but when they click the submit button, the page just refreshes itself - but it should be taking the user to their dashboard (user profile screen).

I can't seem to pinpoint why. Though here is what I get back from the database:

```
   Started POST "/login" for 96.49.105.234 at 2016-01-19 16:50:41 +0000
    Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zo/bLDBFtOAthi/vD8nU5Iqdn3TcsdB/NS8SJKW/l190YC7uXMLw6+EFWl6FPf3hDmVTTN2ozZ4t/8lanYZHhg==", "session"=>{"email"=>"myuser@live.ca", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
      User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "myuser@live.ca"]]
      Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 153ms (Views: 71.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

See code below:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController


  def new
  end

  def create
   user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email] .downcase)

   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

     log_in user
     redirect_to user

   else

     render 'new'

     end
  end

def destroy
end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    #Returns the current logged-in user

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

        <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password


  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    render "new"
  end
end



private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

end
```

Comment: What does the user.authenticate method does? It seems the conditional block is failing at `User.authenticate` condition.

Comment: Right authenticate is the problem I think. Could you past in your User model?

Comment: @Cyzanfar See user.rb pasted above :)

Comment: where is your instance method `authenticate` declared in your User model?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Ahh perhaps that's what I'm missing. I was under the impression my user.rb file did that. Just pasted my users_controller.rb above. PS - apologies for my newb question; still trying to wrap my head around rails!

Comment: No worries we all went through that at some point :). So you are not using Devise for user authentication right? You are trying to build your own from scratch correct?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Correct :)

Comment: Here is an excellent resource http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: @Cyzanfar You rock - thank you!

Comment: @Cyzanfar Strange update: When I create a user in the rails console, I can log in just fine (success!!) it's only when I create a user via the sign up form that I have an issue logging in the created user.

Comment: In your `UsersController` methods like `new` and `show` should be public not private.